# Resulting KSQL join stream shows no data

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am joining a KSQL stream and a KSQL Table. Both are mapped to same key.

But no data is coming to the resulting stream.

```
create stream kz_yp_loan_join_by_bandid WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='kz_yp_loan_join_by_bandid',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS 
select ypl.loan_id, ypl.userid ,ypk.name as user_band_id_name 
FROM kz_yp_loan_stream_partition_by_bandid ypl 
     INNER JOIN kz_yp_key_table ypk 
     ON ypl.user_band_id = ypk.id;
```

No data is in stream kz_yp_loan_join_by_bandid

But if I do simply :

```
select ypl.loan_id, ypl.userid ,ypk.name as user_band_id_name 
FROM kz_yp_loan_stream_partition_by_bandid ypl 
     INNER JOIN kz_yp_key_table ypk 
     ON ypl.user_band_id = ypk.id;
```

There is data present.

It shows that stream is not written but why is it so?

I have tried doing entire setup again.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

1. If you want to process all the existing data as well as new data, make sure that before you run your `CREATE STREAM … AS SELECT` ("CSAS") you have run `SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';`
2. If the join is returning data when run outside of the CSAS then this may not be relevant, but always good to check your join is going to match [all the requirements](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html#join-requirements)
3. Check the KSQL server log in case there's an issue with writing to the target topic, creating the schema on the Schema Registry, etc.

These references will be useful:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-2